# How can I permanently delete my site's URL from a question?

Tags: support

I accidentally included identifiable information about my site in one of my questions. I've edited the question to replace my site URL with `example.com`, but you can easily see what the site was in the edits.

It says that deleting the question can result in not being able to ask questions in the future.

How can I purge the edits so that my site's URL no longer shows up?

Comment: **You** can't, but you can flag that question with a custom mod flag and explain the situation. They either clean up the revision history themselves or notify a SE employee/community manager to do that.

Comment: We can do it ourselves now. We line the diamonds up in just the right way, refracting light just so, and it can erase history. Do note, though, that in many cases, the horse has already left the barn. We cannot clean up the entire Internet, and SO has *many* scraper sites.

Answer (score 2):

Flag the question with 'In need of moderator intervention' and explain your situation, since you cannot edit or delete the revision history yourself. The mods can either get this done themselves, or they can get a StackEmployee to assist you in editing the revision history.